# How do I detect page preloads from chrome extensions?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, monitoring

I have built an extension that keeps track of all the pages which are loaded in a browser session. Recently, I started seeing extra pages in my logs, pages that were not getting actually rendered on the browser.

I tried to find out more about it and learned that it is the "page preload" feature of the browser that these websites are using. Basically, if you specify a link tag with preload option, the associated page will be loaded silently in the background (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content). For these pages, three of the four `chrome.webNavigation` events are getting fired - `onBeforeNavigate`, `onCommitted` and `onDOMContentLoaded`. I also looked into the `transitionQualifier` of the `onCommitted` event but does not give enough information to single out page preloads.

Any ideas around how do I detect that the page was not loaded in the conventional sense but was preloaded?

Also, if someone knows how can I disable the page preload feature in Chrome through commandline switches, I might just block all preloads and my extension would still work.

Comment: This is a part of HTML5 specification so there is no way to disable it, more info in https://crbug.com/785125. It should be detectable by checking if `tabId` is `-1` in the details parameter of onBeforeNavigate, otherwise it's a bug that you can report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as well. For my background page preloads also, I am getting tabId as a positive integer value.

Comment: "my background page preloads also" - what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: What I mean is there are some pages that I am consciously visiting. I can see these pages getting rendered by the browser. In the meantime, there are pages that the browser 'preloads' in the background in the assumption that they might be visited.

From any of the fields that are a part of onBeforeNavigate or navigationCommitted event, I am not able to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Well, apparently it's because this is exactly the same type of activity from the browser's view point.